# Unable to run server with node

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to node js and programming. I have problems running the server. This is what I did

1) Install Express

```
sudo npm install -g express-generator
```

2) Install dependencies

```
cd  . && sudo npm install
```

When I run in terminal:

```
node app.js OR node app
```

There is no response on whether the server is running and chrome says that no data is received when I route to localhost:3000. I later found out that the correct way was to run

```
npm start
```

instead, but I got this:

```
npm ERR! express@0.0.1 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the express@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the express package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls express
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
npm ERR! command "/opt/node/bin/node" "/opt/node/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/apple/Documents/javascript/express
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.14-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple/Documents/javascript/express/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I don't know the detail. Generally, IMO, the most node.js server middle-ware modules are mess, including Express. Especially if you are new, I recommend not to use them, instead, you write server from a scratch.

Comment: Read /Users/apple/Documents/javascript/express/npm-debug.log.

Comment: sudo? ugh.  That being said I think your problem is 2) Install dependencies.  npm install run as root will install dependencies for the root user.  You have to run as root when placing things with the -g (global) flag so the result can be used by everyone, but otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

What did you get in return when you run `node app.js`?

Also, make sure your `app.js` is inside the folder you are at.

Answer (score 0):

Express generator does not generate an express for you, it only installs `express` tool to generate projects.

```
sudo npm install -g express-generator
```

Once `express-generator` is installed; issue `express` to generate the project for you;

```
$ express myapp

// generate myapp with initial express files

$ cd myapp && npm install

// now you run the app
$ ./bin/www

// or
$ npm start
```